# Inefficient function loads on short text, but can't load when given a super long text to analyse

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, counter, python-3.6

I am creating a function to count the number of times each word is in a long text. When I use the below function for a short text, it runs fine without problem. However, when running it with a super long text, it takes too long and it never gets to return the answer.

I believe my code below is ineffecient, and has redundant parts that makes it take too long to load. Is there a better way that is more effecient?

```
def analyse_frequency(x): 
    z = {y : x.count(y) for y in x}
    return sorted(z.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse = True)[:10]
```

Comment: are you loading this text from a file ???

Comment: One quick thing I saw is that you are counting the number of times a word appears as many times as that word appear. Try to generate a set of appearing words and count on them: `words=set(x); z={y:x.count(y) for y in words}`

Comment: @rcshon if you don't want to import anything , do checkout my edited asnwer

Answer (score 2):

`list.count` has O(*n*) complexity. Running an O(*n*) operation in a loop will be especially inefficient. At a minimum it will have complexity O(*m* * *n*), where *m* is the number of unique words.

Instead, you can use `collections.Counter` for an O(*n*) solution:

```
words = 'this is a test string of words containing repeated words within the string'

from collections import Counter

c = Counter(words.split())

res = c.most_common(5)

[('string', 2), ('words', 2), ('this', 1), ('is', 1), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, however, as this is a school assignment, we are not allowed to import anything to aid us.. Is there another way?

Comment: @rcshon, As your question stands, no. You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), carefully listing *all* your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

To count the frequency of words in a file use **Counter**:

```
from collections import Counter
f=open ("file.txt","r") 
words=Counter(f.read().split())
```

this will give a dictionary output with words as keys and count as their values.

if you don't wish to import anything then I will suggest:

```
f=open("file.txt","r")
count={}
for eacword in f.read().split():
    if eacword not in count:
        count[eachword] = 1
    else:
        count[eachword] += 1
```

As per Nearo's suggestion you can avoid the if else through:

```
f=open("file.txt","r")
count={}
for eacword in f.read().split():
    count[eachword]=count.get(eachword,0)+1
```

Comment: to avoide if/else: `count[eachword] = count.get(eachword, 0) + 1`